# Reduce size of c program without optimizing compiler

Tags: c, optimization, compilation, compiler-optimization

Im trying to make a minesweeper game in c which is compact enough to fit into a qr code, like some other people have done with snake. As it stands, my program needs to be around 2.98 KB and is currently 58KB.

Before I move on to trying to make some compiler magic happen, I wanted to know how could refine my code pre-compiler. Is my approach workable, would it have to be completely different, or is fitting the minesweeper program into that small of a size impossible without using assembly? My code can be seen here:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WIDTH 100
#define HEIGHT 100
#define BOMBS 799

#define KEY_UP 72
#define KEY_DOWN 80
#define KEY_LEFT 75
#define KEY_RIGHT 77

HANDLE wHnd;
HANDLE rHnd;

void SetGrid(int grid[WIDTH][HEIGHT])
{
    int bomb[2] = { abs(rand() % WIDTH-1) + 1,
                   abs(rand() % HEIGHT-1) + 1 };

    for (int i = 0; i < BOMBS; i++)
    {
        while (grid[bomb[0]][bomb[1]] < -1 || bomb[0] == 0 || bomb[1] == 0 || bomb[0] >= WIDTH-1 || bomb[1] >= HEIGHT-1)
        {
            bomb[0] = abs(rand() % WIDTH-1) + 1;
            bomb[1] = abs(rand() % HEIGHT-1) + 1;
        }

        grid[bomb[0]][bomb[1]] = -9;

        grid[bomb[0] + 1][bomb[1] + 1]++;
        grid[bomb[0] + 1][bomb[1]]++;
        grid[bomb[0]][bomb[1] + 1]++;
        grid[bomb[0] - 1][bomb[1] + 1]++;
        grid[bomb[0]][bomb[1] - 1]++;
        grid[bomb[0] + 1][bomb[1] - 1]++;
        grid[bomb[0] - 1][bomb[1] - 1]++;
        grid[bomb[0] - 1][bomb[1]]++;
    }
}

void ExpandGrid(int fullGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT], int knownGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT], int blankPos[2])
{
    int neighbors[8][2] = {{0,1}, {1,0}, {1,1},
                          {0,-1},        {-1,0},
                          {-1,-1},{-1,1},{1,-1}};
    int curTile[2];

    knownGrid[blankPos[0]][blankPos[1]] = 1;
    if(fullGrid[blankPos[0]][blankPos[1]] != 0) return;

    for(int blck = 0; blck < 8; ++blck)
    {
        curTile[0] = abs(blankPos[0]+neighbors[blck][0]);
        curTile[1] = abs(blankPos[1]+neighbors[blck][1]);
        if(curTile[0] > WIDTH-1 || curTile[1] > HEIGHT-1) continue;

        if(fullGrid[curTile[0]][curTile[1]] == 0 && knownGrid[curTile[0]][curTile[1]] == 0)
        {
            knownGrid[curTile[0]][curTile[1]] = 1;
            ExpandGrid(fullGrid, knownGrid, curTile);
        }
        else if(fullGrid[curTile[0]][curTile[1]] > 0) knownGrid[curTile[0]][curTile[1]] = 1;
    }
}

int main(void)
{

    SMALL_RECT windowSize = { 0, 0, WIDTH - 1, HEIGHT - 1 };

    COORD characterBufferSize = { WIDTH, HEIGHT };
    COORD characterPosition = { 0, 0 };
    SMALL_RECT consoleWriteArea = { 0, 0, WIDTH - 1, HEIGHT - 1 };

    CHAR_INFO consoleBuffer[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

    wHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    rHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    SetConsoleTitle("Minesweeper!");

    SetConsoleWindowInfo(wHnd, TRUE, &windowSize);

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    int startGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT] = { 0 };
    int knownGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT] = { 0 };
    SetGrid(startGrid);

    int startCoord[2] = {0, 0};
    int arrowPos[2] = {0, 0};

    ExpandGrid(startGrid, knownGrid, startCoord);

    while(1)
    {
        if (arrowPos[0] > WIDTH-1) arrowPos[0] = WIDTH-1;
        if (arrowPos[0] < 0) arrowPos[0] = 0;
        if (arrowPos[1] > HEIGHT-1) arrowPos[1] = HEIGHT-1;
        if (arrowPos[1] < 0) arrowPos[1] = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y)
            {

                if (knownGrid[x][y] == 1)
                {
                    if (startGrid[x][y] > 0)
                    {
                        consoleBuffer[x][y].Char.AsciiChar = '0' + startGrid[x][y];
                        consoleBuffer[x][y].Attributes = FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        consoleBuffer[x][y].Char.AsciiChar = 'o';
                        consoleBuffer[x][y].Attributes = (startGrid[x][y] < 0 ? FOREGROUND_RED : FOREGROUND_BLUE) | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    consoleBuffer[x][y].Char.AsciiChar = 00;
                    consoleBuffer[x][y].Attributes = FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY;
                }

                if(arrowPos[0] == x && arrowPos[1] == y)
                {
                    consoleBuffer[x][y].Attributes = BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN;
                }
            }
        }

        WriteConsoleOutputA(wHnd, consoleBuffer, characterBufferSize, characterPosition, &consoleWriteArea);

        switch(getch())
        {
            case KEY_UP:
                arrowPos[0]--;
                break;
            case KEY_DOWN:
                arrowPos[0]++;
                break;
            case KEY_LEFT:
                arrowPos[1]--;
                break;
            case KEY_RIGHT:
                arrowPos[1]++;
                break;
            case '\r':
                ExpandGrid(startGrid, knownGrid, arrowPos);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Better fit for this question at [Code Review.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It can fit as C code if you use obfuscated c.  There are tools available for that.  As for compiled, without optimization... no.

Answer (score 2):

Reducing from 58K to 3K is a pretty big ask.

A few ideas:

- Examine the libraries that are linked in during your build process, and reduce those to the bare minimum; Eliminate calls to library functions that you may be able to write yourself.
- Possibly use shorter types.  Do you need `int`? Can you use a byte (`char`) or a `short` instead?
- Consider what parts of `windows.h` and `stdlib.h` you *really* need.